# React: State won't change onClick and update component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've got a parent component with a state to detect if the user has clicked it, and the parent component uses a child component which contains an item that I want to hide if the user has clicked the parent component.

Here is the parent component:

```
class Parent extends Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      clicked: false
    };
  }

  setClick = () => {
    this.setState({clicked: true});
  };

  render() { 
    // ... 
    return (
      <div onClick={this.setClick}>
        <Child isClicked={this.state.clicked} />
      </div>
    )
  }  
}
```

Here is the child component, inside my return:

```
return (
  <div ...>
      {!props.isClicked && ( ... then render the item ... )}
  </div>
)
```

So when the user clicks on my parent component, I am trying to change the state of `clicked`, and then I'm passing `clicked` as a prop to my child component, and inside the child component an item is rendered depending on the state of `clicked`. Right now, if I click on the parent component, the state is not changing and the item is still being rendered when it isn't supposed to be. What is the problem?

Comment: Did you verify that the state wasn't getting updated? Or is it just not re-rendering? (In the `render` of `Parent` `console.log(this.state)`. If it is updating, the problem will be in the `Child` component, and we will need to see more of it's implementation.

Comment: The code provided does not seem correct. The closing curly brace for render should end after the returns body ends. The child component also isn't properly written.

Comment: I think we need to see more of your child component; the bits that would explain things not working are not included.

Answer (score 0):

You need to access the props in child with `this.props.isclicked`
So you're child component should look like this

```
class Child extends React.Component<{isClicked:boolean}>{
    render(){
        return (
            <div>
               {`I am ${this.props.isClicked ? `clicked` : `not clicked` }`}
           </div>
         )
    }
}
```